# How do I add a navigation link for each one of the cards in the ForEach so that they have there own screen to go to?

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I already have the structs for the views ready but I don't know how to make the cards go to that view. I am quite new! Can someone help?

My Code:

```
struct HomeView: View {
        var SolarCards: [String] = ["MercuryCard", "VenusCard", "EarthCard", "MarsCard", "jupiterCard", "saturnCard", "uranusCard", "neptuneCard"]
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(SolarCards, id: \.self) { cards in
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                             Image(cards)
                            .shadow(color: colorScheme == .dark ? .blue : .purple, radius: 10)
                            .padding(.bottom, 0)
                            .padding(.leading, 10)
                            .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(geometry.frame(in: .global).minX) / -20), axis: (x: 0, y: 10.0, z: 0))
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 260, height: 400)
                }
            }
```

Comment: This might help: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/displaying-a-detail-screen-with-navigationlink

Comment: i already have the different files ready for the corresponding cards and in those files are really big structs so how do I link it? The video you sent just displayed the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AnyView` with the model and set view with each element.

Here is the demo code

```
struct DemoView: View {
    
    var cards: [Cards] = [.init(name: "MercuryCard", view: AnyView(MercuryCard())),
                          .init(name: "VenusCard", view: AnyView(VenusCard())),
                          .init(name: "EarthCard", view: AnyView(EarthCard()))]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(cards, id: \.id) { cards in
                        NavigationLink(destination: cards.view) {
                            Text(cards.name)
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 260, height: 400)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Cards: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var view: AnyView
}

struct MercuryCard: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("MercuryCard")
    }
}

struct VenusCard: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("VenusCard")
    }
}

struct EarthCard: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("EarthCard")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh that works! Thank You sooo much for the help. I didn't know what AnyView was , but now I do. Thanks again!